# Printing PDO query results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to print all the results of a query, but for some reason I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in H:\Some-Location\ on line X

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT adID FROM given WHERE toUser = :userid"; 
    $query_params = array( ':userid' => $_SESSION['user']['ID'] ); 
    try 
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        echo "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
    } 

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $row['adID'];
    }
?>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs and the error show, `execute` returns a boolean: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

You need to call `fetch()` on the statement, not the return value of `execute`. : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

so replace `$result>fetch()` with `$stmt->fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `execute()` method on the `PDOStatement` does not return the results, it only signals if the query succeeded or not (only useful when not using exceptions).

[PHP Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> ```
> public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )
> ```

What you want to do is use the `PDOStatement` itself to get the data:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['adID'];
}
```

**Note:** According to your current logic, the loop will execute even when an exception is thrown. Try either returning from the `catch` block or putting the loop inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

$result is only a boolean holding success/failure of execute statement.

You need to run fetch on $stmt:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['adID'];
            }
```

As per documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php